# How to create a new column which concatenates the column index based on the condition of those columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to combine the index columns for where the row condition is true into a new column.

**Example DataFrame**

| Owner | Bird | Cat | Dog | Fish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Olivia | True | False | False | False |
| Noah | True | True | True | True |
| Emma | False | True | False | True |
| Liam | False | False | True | True |

Below is my code and output.

```
def all_pets(row):
    if row['Bird'] == 'True':
      return 'Bird'
    if row['Cat'] == 'True':
      return 'Bird'
    if row['Dog'] == 'True':
      return 'Bird'
    if row['Fish'] == 'True':
      return 'Bird'
df['Pets'] = df.apply(lambda row:all_pets(row), axis = 1)
df
```

**My Output**

| Owner | Bird | Cat | Dog | Fish | Pets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Olivia | True | False | False | False | Bird |
| Noah | True | True | True | True | Bird |
| Emma | False | True | False | True | Cat |
| Liam | False | False | True | True | Dog |

How can I concatenate to add all animals, not just the first occurrence, and get the output below?

**Expected Output**

| Owner | Bird | Cat | Dog | Fish | Pets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Olivia | True | False | False | False | Bird |
| Noah | True | True | True | True | Bird, Cat, Dog, Fish |
| Emma | False | True | False | True | Cat, Fish |
| Liam | False | False | True | True | Dog, Fish |

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["Pets"] = df.loc[:, "Bird":].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.index[x]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Owner   Bird    Cat    Dog   Fish                  Pets
0  Olivia   True  False  False  False                  Bird
1    Noah   True   True   True   True  Bird, Cat, Dog, Fish
2    Emma  False   True  False   True             Cat, Fish
3    Liam  False  False   True   True             Dog, Fish
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are Boolean values use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas-dataframe-dot) with `columns` then [`str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html#pandas-series-str-rstrip) to clear up the trailing comma:

```
df['Pets'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
```

Else convert from Strings to Boolean Values via [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace):

```
df['Pets'] = (
    df.iloc[:, 1:].replace({'True': True, 'False': False})
        .dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
)
```

`df`:

```
    Owner   Bird    Cat    Dog   Fish                  Pets
0  Olivia   True  False  False  False                  Bird
1    Noah   True   True   True   True  Bird, Cat, Dog, Fish
2    Emma  False   True  False   True             Cat, Fish
3    Liam  False  False   True   True             Dog, Fish
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your code as the following:

```
def all_pets(row):
    pets = []
    if row['Bird'] == 'True':
        pets.append('Bird')
    if row['Cat'] == 'True':
        pets.append('Cat')
    if row['Dog'] == 'True':
        pets.append('Dog')
    if row['Fish'] == 'True':
        pets.append('Fish')
    return ', '.join(pets)

df['Pets'] = df.apply(lambda row:all_pets(row), axis = 1)
```

Your original function just returns a single string at a time, so I change it to return a list and use the join function to concatenate all elements in the list with a comma and a white space.

Another method is to transform a list into an array and thus you can subset a part of elements in a list.

```
pets = np.array(['Bird','Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'])
df['Pets'] = df[pets].apply(lambda row: ', '.join(pets[np.array(row)=="True"]), axis = 1)
```

Hope this answer helps!